# %in% does not returns atomic result

Tags: r, dplyr

In this operation, `x` is a `tbl_df`, and `outliers` is a `data.frame`.
But `id` returns a `logical`, not a `tbl_df`.

What am i doing wrong?

```
x <- as_tibble(c(rep(2,10),50,64,80))
boxplot1 <-
  ggplot (data=x, aes_string (x = factor(0), y = "x" )) + 
  geom_boxplot (fill = "lightgreen", outlier.fill = "darkgreen") + 
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar', color = "grey") +
  coord_flip () +
  ggtitle (paste0 ("x", ", with outliers"))
outliers <- data.frame (unlist (ggplot_build(boxplot1)$data[[1]][6],use.names = F),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
id <- x %in% outliers
```

I expected a tbl_df with the same length that x. Indeed, id <- match(outliers,x) returns a numeric of length outliers, but id <- match(x,outliers) does not return a numeric of length x

Comment: Nothing. The `%in%` function returns a logical vector, as it states in the documentation.

Comment: I expected a `tbl_df` with the same length that `x`. Indeed, `id <- match(outliers,x)` returns a numeric of length `outliers`, but `id <- match(x,outliers)` does not return a numeric of length `x`.

Comment: Please provide example data.  I tried to recreate your problem with the `mtcars` data, one a tibble with a single column and the other a data.frame with a subset of that column.  `%in%` always returned a single logical value, which makes sense. Both `x` and `outliers` are lists of length 1.  So you're not checking if each row's value is in the other, but if the entire column is exactly in the other.

Comment: Added example. I need an atomic operation with `outliers` in `x`. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was put `id` in brakets `id <- x[[1]] %in% outliers[[1]]`, but I do not understand why.

Comment: Both `x` and `outliers` are tibbles, which are data.frames, which are lists. Their "list form" is the list of columns. `x %in% outliers` means, "for each element in `x`, is it in `outliers`?"  Since `x` (as a list) has only one element (the column), `x %in% outliers` answers "is the column in `x` also a column in `outliers`?"

Comment: Thanks! I understand you. 
a) The first bracket downgrade to the column content of the tibbles: "is the element list in `x` also a element list in `outliers`?"
b) The second bracket downgrade to a specific list content of the element list selected (a double vector): "are the elements of the vector contained in the first element of list of tibble-column `x` also a identical value in the same position into the double-vector in the first element of the list from the `outliers` tibble?".
This example shagged me about tidyverse is more conceptual. Are another form to resolve atomic ops?

Comment: Following the example, I have to obtain a simple filtered mean with 
`m2 <- mean(x[!id,][[1]], na.rm = T)`